# Yii2: Standalone validation not triggering client validation

Tags: validation, yii2

Validation functions don't work. 
Validation customs rules are not applied to the `usernmane` field

```
module dektrium/user
PHP 7.1
Yii 2.0.16
```

Already try all from here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation (Inline Validators  and Standalone Validators)

Model Agent :

```
class Agent extends Profile
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $password2;

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            ['username', AgentValidator::className()],// it's not work
            [['email'], 'email'], // it's work
            ['password2', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'message' => 'Пароли должны совпадать'],//// it's work
        ];
        return array_merge(parent::rules(), $rules);
    }

}
```

AgentValidator.php

```
<?php
namespace app\components;
use yii\validators\Validator;

class AgentValidator extends  Validator
{
    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
      if (User::findOne(['username' => $this->$attribute]]) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Такой логин уже занят');

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am currently using around 4 standalone validators with PHP 7.2 and there isn't any problem with them

Comment: also please add the base model `Profile` that you are extending this model from

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have tried custom validation in other models and forms. Does not work too . But in another project, everything is OK. Just fun =)  I will try to reinstall the YII2 kernel and dependencies.

Comment: how are you triggering the validation ? by calling the `$model->validate()` ?

Comment: can you show your controller action code how are you calling the validation after submitting the form?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, as far as i know, yii generate some js code? base on model rules, like this: ` ,{"id":"agent-username","name":"username","container":".field-agent-username","input":"#agent-username","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {yii.validation.required(value, messages, {"message":"Необходимо заполнить «Логин»."});}}` 
But for some reason does not do it for custom validators. Controller add to main message

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Оh! I understand =)

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thank you! I added ajax validation in form and ajax validation in Controller. It's work. So, for custom validation rule Yii doesn't generate any js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using standalone validator and you want the frontend validation to be working along with the backend so you need to override the [`yii\validators\Validator::clientValidateAttribute()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#clientValidateAttribute()-detail) in your Standalone validator `AgentValidator`, which returns a piece of JavaScript code that performs the validation on the client-side.

Within the JavaScript code, you may use the following predefined variables:

- `attribute`: the name of the attribute being validated.
- `value`: the value being validated.
- `messages`: an array used to hold the validation error messages for the attribute.
- `deferred`: an array which deferred objects can be pushed into.

You can go through the section [Implementing Client Validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#implementing-client-side-validation) to read in detail.

Apart from everything listed above you have a mistake in your validator code `User::findOne(['username' => $this->$attribute]]`, you need to use `$model->$attribute` rather than `$this->$attribute` which will never get the exact value entered in the form. You might have mistakenly added it from the model.

Your current validator should be like below

```
<?php
namespace app\components;
use yii\validators\Validator;

class AgentValidator extends  Validator
{
    public $message='Такой логин уже занят';

    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
        if (User::findOne(['username' => $model->$attribute])!==null) 
        {
            $model->addError($attribute, $this->message);
        }
    }

    public function clientValidateAttribute($model, $attribute, $view) {
        //check if user exists
        $userExists = User::findOne(['username' => $model->$attribute])!==null;

        $message = json_encode($this->message, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

        return <<<JS
            if($userExists){
                messages.push($message);
                return;
            }
JS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, Thank Muhammad Omer Aslam for right answer.
Yii2 does't generate any js code for validation by custom rules. Therefore it is necessary to add a check to the controller and the form
For me it:
Controller

```
  if (\Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());
            return \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
```

Form

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'enableAjaxValidation' => true]);
```

Comment: umm ... i didnt exactly mean to say that ,look into the answer below i have added, yii does provide you an option to add the client side validation, instead it wsa never clear you were asking about the client side validation